# Node Update Problem on hook Cron

Tags: nodes, hooks, cron

I am trying to update a node in a `hook_cron()` function. I am using Drupal 6.

Here is my code:

```
function offers_cron() {
  $query= db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} WHERE type = 'product'");
  while($allnodes = db_fetch_object($query)){
    $node_id=$allnodes->nid;
    $node=node_load($node_id);
    
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->nid = $node_id;  
    
    $node->type = 'product';
    $node->language = 'en';
    $node->uid=1;
    $node->status = 1; 
    $node->created = time();
    $node->changed = $node->created;
    $node->comment=0;
    $node->promote = 0; 
    $node->sticky = 0;  
    $node->format = 2;  
    $node->title='test';
    $node->field_price[0]['value']='120';

    if ($node = node_submit($node)) {
      node_save($node);
      drupal_set_message(t("Node ".$node->title." added correctly"));
    } else {
      drupal_set_message(t("Node ".$node->title." added incorrectly"), "error");
    }
  }
}
```

Now it shows it has updated all nodes. Here is screen shot for this :

[image]

Now when I click any node the update does not show.

Please take a look:

[image]

Does anybody have any ideas about this?

I have even tried clearing the cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution: If the node doesn't change, don't create a new revision.